# Apache Spark: How to Send custom messages from Executor to Driver

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to send some custom messages from Executor to Driver In Apache Spark? It is quite evident from driver and executor logs that there is a a lot of framework level communication is happening however I did not find any API to send custom messages between processes. Please advise.

Comment: Hi there! Did you find any solution? In my case, I want to send a message/event from the executors to the driver during a mapPartitions function. I was wondering if there is some way to send a custom event and receive it in a SparkListener in the onOtherEvent function

Comment: I did not find solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Accumulators!
read about it: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/advanced_spark_programming.htm

You can not send messages, but you can aggregate data at executors and use it at the driver after the parallel computation ends.

Comment: Not sure if Accumulators can be used for custom messages. Spark docs have a warning about silent failures. `Warning: When a Spark task finishes, Spark will try to merge the accumulated updates in this task to an accumulator. If it fails, Spark will ignore the failure and still mark the task successful and continue to run other tasks. Hence, a buggy accumulator will not impact a Spark job, but it may not get updated correctly although a Spark job is successful.`